# Matrix multiplication using Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to perform a matrix multiplication on a simple 3 X 3 matrix using Pig. I'm neither unable to perform transpose nor group according to the row.

Can someone help me on this please.

Example

Matrix A:

```
2  2  2 
2  2  2
2  2  2
```

Matrix B:

```
1  1  1
1  1  1    
1  1  1
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are the matrices stored? Is A a relation where each row is a tuple with the matrix row? Is A a relation where each relation is a bag with a matrix in it (several matrices in one relation or only one in each relation)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your matrices are stored as "row, column, value", you can check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32980359/2715118)

Also if you have a txt file for the same, you can load that by:

```
E = LOAD 'matrix1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (row:chararray, col:chararray, val:float);
```

OR

```
E = LOAD 'M-matrix-small.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (row, col, val);
```